# How to modify XML element based on other element in file?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML document that looks like the following:

```xml
<outer>
    <item name="1"/>
    <item name="2"/>
    <item name="3"/>

    <map>
        <entry ref="1" a="foo"/>
        <entry ref="2" a="bar"/>
    </map>
</outer>
```

I want to remove the `map` element and store the attributes directly on the `item` elements, so that the result looks like this:

```xml
<outer>
    <item name="1" a="foo"/>
    <item name="2" a="bar"/>
    <item name="3"/>
</outer>
```

Somehow, I think this might be possible with a recursive XSLT template, but I have to admit that I'm completely clueless.

Also, if you think it is complete madness doing this using XSLT, let me know and I'll use a full programming language for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="//entry[@ref=$name]/@a">
            <xsl:attribute name="a" select="//entry[@ref=$name]/@a"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyA/6

Comment: That's great! Your solution is also easily adjustable to my real problem. One thing: In my processor, I could not use `select` attribute in `xsl:attribute`, but I could use a `xsl:value-of` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need recursion.

Define a key:

```
<xsl:key name="K" match="entry" use="ref"/>
```

and then do

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <item name="{@name}" a="{key('K', @name)/@a}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed then we can help you. Just telling us you went wrong somewhere doesn't provide a way forward. (It seems @SudeepRawat has provided you a complete working solution, though it's not a very efficient one. I'm afraid I don't believe in providing complete working solutions, because I think there's a tendency for people to use them without understanding how they work, and people then just come back here with the next problem having not really learnt anything).

Comment: I can understand this stance, and it's ok. Just to clarify: I spent some time (1h+) to try to get your approach with `key` to work. Still if you would have provided a working solution, I probably could have adapted it to my actual problem (problem in OP is simplified). Now trying to adapt your solution and fill in the blanks at the same time was probably too much for me to handle with my limited knowledge of XSLT. I don't want to say this is a bad answer (otherwise I'd have -1), but I cannot +1, since I couldn't confirm that it works.

Comment: I think I could have found the accepted solution myself. But I kept having problems with `@name`, probably name clash. Maybe I had the same problem with your solution.